# how to append different functions but the same interface in slice

Tags: go

I tried to append different functions that can be represented with the same interface. 
Functions return different objects but same interface.
It failed with the error `cannot use Test (value of type func() *Dog) as func() Animal value in argument to append (typecheck)`
What should I do? Thanks in advance!

```golang
package main

type Dog struct {
    Word string
}

type Cat struct {
    Word string
}

func (d *Dog) Say() string {
    return d.Word
}

func (c *Cat) Say() string {
    return c.Word
}

type Animal interface {
    Say() string
}

func main() {
    funcs := []func() Animal{}
    funcs = append(funcs, Test)  // error| cannot use Test (value of type func() *Dog) as func() Animal value in argument to append (typecheck)
}

func Test() *Dog {
    return &Dog{Word: "dog"}
}

func Test2() *Cat {
    return &Cat{Word: "cat"}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your functions to have `Animal` as their return type. `func() *Dog` is not convertible to `func() Animal`, they are two separate data types.

Similar to how you can pass, say, `int` as `interface{}`, but not `[]int` as `[]interface{}`

Comment: this is a simple example，my actual situation is interface defined in upper level code，the return type define in different packages

Comment: @柚子youthy: in this case, take a look at the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The slice element and functions have different return types. Use anonymous functions to convert the function return values to the slice element return type.

```
funcs = append(funcs, 
     func() Animal { return Test() }, 
     func() Animal { return Test2() })

for _, f := range funcs {
    fmt.Println(f().Say())
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L32uKhSxy1c).

Another option is to use the reflect package to call the function and convert the result to an Animal.

```
func makeAnimal(f interface{}) Animal {
    // This function assumes that f is a function
    // that returns a value that satisfies the
    // Animal interface.

    result := reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(nil)
    return result[0].Interface().(Animal)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
funcs := []interface{}{}
funcs = append(funcs, Test, Test2)
for _, f := range funcs {
    a := makeAnimal(f)
    fmt.Println(a.Say())
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z13sBOmr_AO).

Comment: just what I need！ wrap in an anonymous function worked！

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `func () *Dog` cannot converts to `func() Animal`.
If you don't wanna use reflection, you have to change the "funcs" type to `[]interface{}` then cast each element of the slice into `func() *Dog` and simply call it, like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Dog struct {
    Word string
}

type Cat struct {
    Word string
}

func (d *Dog) Say() string {
    return d.Word
}

func (c *Cat) Say() string {
    return c.Word
}

type Animal interface {
    Say() string
}

func main() {
    var funcs []interface{}

    funcs = append(funcs, Test)
    fmt.Println(funcs[0].(func() *Dog)().Say()) // prints "dog"
}

func Test() *Dog {
    return &Dog{Word: "dog"}
}

func Test2() *Cat {
    return &Cat{Word: "cat"}
}
```